# Opentok continuous window reload

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

When I start the video chat, the video window on both clients closes and reopens every 2 seconds. There is a flood of messages on the console, but they're all from the openTok javascript file. It has something to do with how the session.publish(publisher) function is being called, but I'm not sure what the problem is. This issue is new - it was working fine last week, and I haven't touched either the client nor the server code since then. Backups that DID work don't now. Has anything on the Tokbox side changed recently?

if anyone could take a look at my code, I'd appreciate it.

my client code is at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1135279/
Here is the console output, with the last 6 lines being repeated every time the window opens and closes.

```
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.setLogLevel(4)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: Session.connect(413302)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.checkSystemRequirements()
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.removeEventListener(sessionConnected)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(sessionConnected)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.removeEventListener(streamCreated)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(streamCreated)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(exception)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.removeEventListener(exception)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(exception)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.setLogLevel(4)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.checkSystemRequirements()
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(exception)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.removeEventListener(exception)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(exception)
chat:373TB.addEventListener
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.initSession(1_MX40MTMzMDJ-flR1ZSBBdWcgMDcgMTc6MzU6MDIgUERUIDIwMTJ-MC4zMzExMDQ3fg)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.removeEventListener(sessionConnected)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(sessionConnected)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.removeEventListener(sessionDisconnected)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(sessionDisconnected)
chat:377Uncaught ReferenceError: connectionCreatedHandler is not defined
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.sessionConnected: 1_MX40MTMzMDJ-flR1ZSBBdWcgMDcgMTc6MzU6MDIgUERUIDIwMTJ-MC4zMzExMDQ3fg - 5f4c204130c5bb9c7ba058dbb7da96fbb377e09d
chat:322sessionConnectedHandler
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.initPublisher(cPMLG7xrBPaEfhFwo2mvdrCkvPOe4NywvideoBox)
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: Session.publish([object Object]):undefined
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: Pending: publishToSession(1_MX40MTMzMDJ-flR1ZSBBdWcgMDcgMTc6MzU6MDIgUERUIDIwMTJ-MC4zMzExMDQ3fg,5f4c204130c5bb9c7ba058dbb7da96fbb377e09d,T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00MTMzMDImc2lnPTBiYThlMzVjYWY3OGQzNDk0MTA0ZmZhOTEwZjRlZDNjOTNhYjg2MTc6c2Vzc2lvbl9pZD0xX01YNDBNVE16TURKLWZsUjFaU0JCZFdjZ01EY2dNVGM2TXpVNk1ESWdVRVJVSURJd01USi1NQzR6TXpFeE1EUTNmZyZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xMzQ0Mzg2MTAzJm5vbmNlPTMwNzk0MyZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlcg==) on component publisher_1
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.connectionCreated
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceAccessHandler: accessDialogOpened
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.resize
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.resize
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceAccessHandler: accessDialogClosed
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceAccessHandler: accessDenied
TB.min.js:251[DEBUG] opentok: Pending: cleanupView() on component publisher_1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late to answer, but looking from the logs it looks like you are not listening to sessionConnectedHandler, which can cause some problems if you try to publish/subscribe to video streams before session is connected. You can find release notes [here](http://tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/docs/js/release-notes.html) to see if any code has been changed.